# How to slide a specific web part(HTML) when User rollover the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi can anyone suggest me some code for below scenario:

If user mouseover/rollover the button a web part should open in sliding manner
Say for eg: if there is a button called "click here" which has been positioned in right side of webpage it should open its contents in sliding manner from right to left

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring jQuery. There are lots of function through which you can achieve this.

Check this sample [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).

Hope this helps.